# Creación de listas en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo estas listas:

```
lista0 = ["roy",25,"madrid","casado"]
lista1 = ["luis",30,"barcelona","soltero"]
```

Y esta lista sigue hacia abajo.

Lo que quiero es asignarle un `id` numérico a cada lista donde yo busco la lista "x" a ese `id`.

Por Ej: 20115

Así el programa cuando me pida que inserte el `id` de la persona que deseo buscar, en vez de buscar por el nombre de la lista en especifico, busco por el `id` de la lista.

No se como hacerlo o si se puede, soy nuevo en python y agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Y por qué no utilizar un `dict`? `lista = { 20115:["roy", ... ] }` ?

Answer (score 1):

Una solución que te puede ayudar mejor que utlizar una `list`, es utilizar `dict`, al hacer:

```
lista = {
    0:[ "Roy", 20, "Madrid", "Casado" ],
    1:[ "Luis", 30, "Barcelona", "Soltero" ]
}
```

Al hacer:

```
print(lista[0])
```

Obtienes por resultado:

```
[ "Roy", 20, "Madrid", "Casado" ]
```

Imaginando que necesitas agregar algún nuevo registro, simplemente haces:

```
lista[ID] = [ ... ] # Donde '...' son los valores que tendrá el elemento ID.
```

#### Edit,

Asumiendo que los datos estaran en posiciones estaticas, puedes utilizar el siguiente método para lograr cambiar las propiedades de cada `ID`:

```
# Definimos un dict para almacenar los IDs con sus valores
lista = {
    0:[ "Roy", 20, "Madrid", "Casado" ],
    1:[ "Luis", 30, "Barcelona", "Soltero" ]
}
# Definimos los indices donde vamos a guardar las cosas:
Nombre = 0
Edad = 1 
Ciudad = 2
EstadoCivil = 3  # Estado civil está en el indice 3, no 4 (ojo)

ID = int(input('Escriba el ID que desea obtener: '))
print('El nombre del sujeto es: ' + str(lista[ID][Nombre])) # Imprime el nombre 'Roy'
# E imprime sucesivamente la información necesaria.
```

Comment: me gusta tu idea y podria cambiar el valor de algun elemento de una de las sublistas

Comment: ¿Lo preguntas o lo afirmas?

Comment: lo preguntaba y digamos que yo quiero agregar en la lista un elemento 3 pero en vez de 3 quiero quese llame 2201 y el nombre,edad,ciudad,estadocivil se digite por teclado

Comment: @LuisDavidJimenez Si lo que quiere es que el `ID` sea 2201, no hay problema, lo que no pueden es repetirse los `ID`s.

Comment: y si lo hago asi def ID():
    id = input("DIGITE ID ESTUDIANTE")
    nombre = input("digite nombre")
    edad = input("digite edad")
    ciudad = input("digite direccion")
    estadocivil = input("digite estado civil")
    estudiantes = {
    id: [nombre, edad, ciudad, estadocivil],
    }
    print(estudiantes)
    
como hago para hacer varias listas e incluirlas en una misma para buscarla por id

Comment: lo pregunto    ...............

Comment: Asumiendo que tienes una lista creada: `lista[id] = [ nombre, edad, ciudad, estadocivil ]`, siempre y cuando utilices el método mencionado anteriormente debería de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Y si haces un arreglo de tu listas?
Vale decir

```
lista = ["roy",25,"madrid","casado"];
listaMaestro.append(lista);

lista1 = ["luis",30,"barcelona","soltero"];
listaMaestro.append(lista);
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo, ya que la manera mas conveniente es con un ciclo `for` el cual cada vez que defines una lista, lo agregaras como un nuevo elemento a tu `listaMaestro`, y luego por el indice lo podrás buscar (listaMaestro[20115]). A esto se le considera una **Matriz** donde se habla mas de una dimensión.

Finalmente si quieres ver la informacion de uno de ellos, por ejemplo de luis, este dato sera extraido asi:

```
print(lista[1]);
```

Obtienes por resultado:

```
["luis",30,"barcelona","soltero"];
```

Espero haberte ayudado o al menos dado una idea de como seguir desempeñando tu proyecto, saludos y exito! :D

Comment: El último ejemplo arroja `TypeError: Unhashable Type: List` en python 3.5.2 [repl.it](https://repl.it/HHW1)

Comment: el ultimo ejemplo fue solo un ejemplo visual de lo que seria listaMaestro, para que entendieras que es lo que tienes y que los esta separando, para entender lo que esta haciendo por debajo el código :D Igual lo edite para que se entendiera mejor